# A frame in **Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres**

Tags: mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from 242th page of

*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214438998), J. Differ. Geom. 20, 237-266 (1984). [ZBL0556.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0556.53001).

> [image]

$H$ is the mean curvature. I don't know how to get the red line under this frame. In my view, 
$$
\nabla H =(\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_n})
$$
and 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}=e_1 =\frac{\nabla H}{|\nabla H|}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A frame" is not a global coordinate system, but rather a collection of bases for tangent spaces, say near a point as in the above text. If one introduces a frame where $e_1(p)=\frac{\nabla H(p)}{|\nabla H(p)|}$ then when using the basis that is given by the frame the vector $\nabla H(p)$ is written as a linear combination of basis vectors as $$\nabla H(p)= |\nabla H(p)| e_1(p) +0 e_2(p)+\ldots +0 e_n(p)$$ Thus, since the frame is orthonormal at each point, $\nabla_i H(p)= \nabla H(p)  \cdot  e_i(p)$ is as in the "red line".

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to understand $\nabla H=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}g^{ij}$ ?

Comment: What is the context for this second equation? I presume it's the same paper, but what section?

Comment: @lanse7pty, $\nabla H$ is a tangent vector field, so the right-hand side is just decomposition to n-linear independent tangent vectors at a point.